# Failed to download vendor/package from source... isn't in the same repository

Tags: svn, composer-php, vendor, toran-proxy

I'm trying to get the new revision from **SVN** and updating my composer.lock but I get this error:

(I'm using toran proxy)

```
Failed to download vendor/package from source: Package could not be downloaded,
svn: E170000: 'https://user:password@server/path/to/repo/sub-repo/core/trunk/' isn't in the same repository as 'https://repo:password@server/path/to/repo/'
```

Any idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Downgrade svn 1.8 to 1.7.

Or

Remove "user:password@" of URL: `'https://path/to/repo/sub-repo/core/trunk/'`

and wait svn ask user/password.